# MVC: Dynamic ascx to load in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a website that has essentially the same model, the difference is the view. If User A logs in, he will see view A. If User B logs in, he will see view B. It's going to be like that for majority of the pages for the whole site. I read a post, that says I make use of areas. But since I have same models for those pages, I am thinking using only one controller and the controller will determine what view to load. I am thinking to use only one aspx view and then just load the ascx page depending on the user. I don't want to use if statements in my view to determine what ascx to render, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a ViewEngine that searches in a subdirectory of the views folders. In the example UserA will get served the view from the UserA directory, if that does not exist it will get the normal view.

If the Views directory looks like:

```
Views
|-> Home
|   |-> Index.cshtml
|   |-> UserA
|       |-> Index.cshtml
|-> Test
    |-> Index.cshtml
```

Then UserA will get the view from Views/Home/UserA/Index.cshtml and everyone else will get Views/Home/Index.cshtml. Everyone including UserA will get /Views/Test/Index.cshtml served because there is no specific one for UserA.

```
    public class MyViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    {
        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            ViewEngineResult result = null;
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (UserA)
            {
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, "UserA/" + viewName, masterName, useCache);
            }

            //Fall back to normal view if no other view has been selected
            if (result == null || result.View == null)
            {
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
        {
            ViewEngineResult result = null;
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (UserA)
            {
                result = base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, "UserA/" + partialViewName, useCache);
            }

            //Fall back to normal view if no other view has been selected
            if (result == null || result.View == null)
            {
                result = base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you decide which ASCX view you would be showing off and pass it either as part of a ViewModel or in ViewData

```
if (UserA)
{
   ViewData["thePartialView"] = "NameOfPartialViewForUserA"
}
else 
{
   ViewData["thePartialView"] = "NameOfPartialViewForUserB"
}
```

In the View >

```
Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["thePartialView"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Here is a solution to my problem but i do not know if it is the best one.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var action = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (action != null)
        {
            action.MasterName = ViewData["siteConstants"].ToString();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Something like that. I just changed the action.MasterName line. In the Initialize method in my base controller, depending on the user I assigned a value to the ViewData["siteConstants"] which is the name of the master page. I also made use of a customViewEngine in which i specified the custom paths of my master page.